# Select multiple items in GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I am developing a gallery-like Activity. Everything runs fine but there is a key functionality which is missing and I couldn't find a decent answer or explanation. What I need is to give the user the ability to **select multiple items by long clicking** on them. 


Here is the desired result:

[image]

You can clearly see the selected pics and the options in the ActionBar.

My setup is this:

1.I have a *GridView* in my XML:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/gridview"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:columnWidth="90dp"
          android:numColumns="auto_fit"
          android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
          android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
          android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
          android:gravity="center"/>
```

2.It is attached to a class, which extends *BaseAdapter* and loads images using Picasso:

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context mContext;
    List<String> mDataset;

    public GalleryAdapter(Context context, List<String> dataset) {
        mContext = context;
        mDataset = dataset;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mDataset.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if(convertView == null){
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200,200));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        //TODO: REMOVE INTEGER.VALUEOFF. IT'S MADE FOR MOCK
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(Integer.valueOf(mDataset.get(position))).fit().into(imageView);

        return imageView;
    }


}
```

3.It is attached to the Activity:

```
//Get images paths
List<String> data = getImagesPath(this);
    List<String> sortedData = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String file : data){
        sortedData.add(0, file);
    }

    GalleryAdapter adapter = new GalleryAdapter(this, sortedData);
    mGallery.setAdapter(adapter);
```

From now on the struggle begins:

- I tried making my item in the GridView to implement *Checkable*:

  ```
  public class CheckableItem extends LinearLayout implements Checkable{
  private boolean mIsChecked = false;
  private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = { android.R.attr.state_checked };

  public CheckableItem(Context context) {
      super(context);
  }

  @Override
  protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
      int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
      if (isChecked())
          mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
      return drawableState;
  }

  @Override
  public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
      mIsChecked = checked;
      refreshDrawableState();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isChecked() {
      return mIsChecked;
  }

  @Override
  public void toggle() {
      setChecked(!isChecked());
      refreshDrawableState();
  }
  ```

Then I load it in my XML and added `.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)` to my *GridView* in the Activity. Nothing Happened.

- Added *MultiChoiceModeListener*:

  `class MultiChoiceListener implements GridView.MultiChoiceModeListener{
      @Override
      public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
          int selectCount = mGallery.getCheckedItemCount();
          switch (selectCount) {
              case 1:
                  mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
                  break;
              default:
                  mode.setSubtitle("" + selectCount + " items selected");
                  break;
          }
      }`

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
      mode.setTitle("Select Items");
      mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
      return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
      return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
      return false;
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

  }
  ```

  }

Then added it to my gridView `.setMultiChoiceModeListener(newMultiChoiceListener());` but still no results.

Can someone propose a way to achieve this item selecting behavior in *GridView*? I'd like to use the native Android API, no 3rd party libraries.

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem. Did you solved this issue ?

Comment: See the accepted answer. Your only way is to implement the selection functionality yourself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think Checkable and the rest that I see in your code is a bit of an overkill...When I want to implement something like that I just add another field in the class of the object that is shown in the GridView/ListView which stores the checked state of the object. example:

```
class Image {
     Bitmap bm;
     boolean isChecked=false;

     public Image(Bitmap bm){
        this.bm=bm;
     }

     public boolean isChecked(){
         return isChecked;
     }
     public void toggleChecked(){
         isChecked = !isChecked;
     }
}
```

and feed an ArrayList to the adapter. an in the getView method of the adapter I do something like this;

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 

     if(images.get(position).isChecked()){
        //show the overlay view that suggests the item is selected
     }
     else{
        //hide the overlay view 
     } 
}
```

finally in the onItemClickListener of the ListView

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        images.get(position).toggleChecked();
        listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```