# Multi selection in Gridview- not able to change the background of selected items of GridView

Tags: android

I am working on a Gallary App, all goes well so far.Now I wanted to implement delete functionality, for that user must be able to select the desired items to delete.slection is working fine but the issue is that selected items are not highlighted.So the user is able to view the count of the selected item, not the highlighted selected items.

For this, i am using **GridView.MultiChoiceModeListener**

```
public class MultiChoiceModeListener implements GridView.MultiChoiceModeListener

{
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.setTitle("Select Items");
        mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_action_mode, menu);
        return true;

    }

    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "item clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    }

    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
        int selectCount = mView.getCheckedItemCount();

        switch (selectCount) {
            case 1:
                mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
                break;
            default:
                mode.setSubtitle("" + selectCount + " items selected");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

using above code snippet I am able to get the count of selected items but not able to highlight the selected items.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select multiple items in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35928051/select-multiple-items-in-gridview)

Comment: The response of that Question is not satisfying in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set background color for particular views